# Unsubscribe from Sails models when client logs out

Tags: javascript, authentication, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm making use of Sails' [resourceful pubsub](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub) to subscribe to models and handle auto-emitted changes with `sails.io`.  What is the best way, on either `client` or `server`, to remove a particular client's subscriptions if they `log out`?